# Decomposition of $H(z)$ as maximum-phase, minimum-phase

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, filter-design, phase, minimum-phase

The frequency response is:

$$H(z) = 2-7z^{-1}+7z^{-2}-2z^{-3}$$

I see that it has $3$ zeros: $z_{01} = \frac 12$, $z_{02} = 2$, and $z_{03} = 1$; and $3$ poles in: $$z_x = 0$$

Now, I have to write it like:

$$H(z) = H_{\rm min}(z) H_{\rm max}(z) H_{\rm uc}(z)$$

where $H_{\rm min}(z)$ is the minimum-phase frequency response, $H_{\rm max}(z)$ is the maximum-phase frequency response and $H_{\rm uc}(z)$ only has zeros on $\lvert z\rvert=1$.

- For $H_{\rm uc}(z)$, I have one zero on $\lvert z\rvert=1$, so:
  $$H_{\rm uc}(z) = z-1$$
  Is that OK?
- For the minimum-phase frequency, I have all the poles/zeros that are inside the unit circle, so:
  $$H_{\rm min}(z) = \frac{z-1/2}{z^3}$$
- For the maximum-phase frequency, I have all the poles/zeros that are outside the unit circle, so:
  $$H_{\rm max}(z) = z-2$$

  But I also know that I can find $H_{\rm max}(z)$ as:
  $$H_{\rm max}(z) = H_{\rm min}\left(z^{-1}\right) z^{-M_i}$$
  where $M_i$ is the quantity of zeros of $H_{\rm min}(z)$. So:
  $$H_{\rm max}(z) = \frac{z^{-1} - 1/2}{z^{-3}} = z^3 \left(z^{-1} - 1/2\right) = z^2 \left(z-1/2\right)$$

  So I have $2$ different expressiones for the same $H_{\rm max}(z)$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check your zeros: there's no zero at $z=3$.

Comment: That's true. It's fixed now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's check that:
$$H(z) = H_{\rm min}(z) H_{\rm max}(z) H_{\rm uc}(z) \tag{1}$$
where:
$$
H_{\rm min}(z) = \frac{z-1/2}{z^3}\tag{2}
$$
and
$$H_{\rm max}(z) = z-2\tag{3}$$
and
$$H_{\rm uc}(z) = z-1\tag{4}$$

Substituting $(2)$, $(3)$, and $(4)$ into $(1)$:

\begin{align}
H_{\rm min}(z) H_{\rm max}(z) H_{\rm uc}(z) &= \frac{z-1/2}{z^3} (z-2) (z-1)\\
 &= \frac{z-1/2}{z^3} \left(z^2 - 3z + 2\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{z^3} \left(z^3 - 3z^2 + 2z - \frac{1}{2}\left(z^2 - 3z + 2\right)\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{z^3} \left( z^3 - \frac{7}{2} z^2 + 5 z - 1\right)  \\
&\not= H(z)
\end{align}

So something is wrong!

Try:
$$
H_{\rm min}(z) = 1-1/2z^{-1}\tag{2A}
$$
and
$$H_{\rm max}(z) = 1-2z^{-1}\tag{3A}$$
and
$$H_{\rm uc}(z) = 2(1- z^{-1})\tag{4A}$$

Now:
\begin{align}
H_{\rm min}(z) H_{\rm max}(z) H_{\rm uc}(z) &= \left(1-1/2z^{-1}\right) \left(1-2z^{-1}\right) \left(1-z^{-1}\right) 2\\
&= \left(1 - \frac{5}{2} z^{-1} + z^{-2}\right) \left(1-z^{-1}\right) 2\\
&= 2 - 5 z^{-1} + 2z^{-2} - \left(2z^{-1} - 5 z^{-2} + 2 z^{-3}\right)\\
&= 2 - 7 z^{-1} + 7 z^{-2} - 2z^{-3}\\
&= H(z)
\end{align}

---

I believe your interpretation of Oppenheim and Schafer (OS) is incorrect. And I can find no reference that says the poles have to be outside the unit circle for a maximum phase system. [This one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_phase#Maximum_phase) and [the one I referenced in the comments](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Maximum_Phase_Filters.html) both only mention the zero locations.

And this is what my copy of OS says:

[image: No mention of pole locations]

which also only mentions zero locations.

I believe exercise 5.63 is in error.  The definition used in the body of the book is:

[image]

which again does not mention pole locations.

Also, having 
$$
H_{\rm max}(z) = H_{\rm min}\left(z^{-1}\right) z^{-M_i}
$$
ensures that $H_{\rm max}$ is causal for FIR $H_{\rm min}$.

So you have two options: either the exercise 5.69 definition is wrong, or the relationship between $H_{\rm max}$ and $H_{\rm min}$ is wrong.

Comment: But why did you choose $H_{uc}(z)=2(1-z^{-1})$ instead of $H_{uc}(z) = 1-(z^{-1})$ ?? Both have a zero at $z=1$ and a pole in $z=0$. What's the difference? How did you choose that scale factor? ----------------------------

By definition, $H_{max}(z)$ has all the poles and zeros outside the unit circle, and you choose a zero at $z=2$ and a pole at $z=0$ (inside the unit circle). Why?

Comment: Your choice of $H_{uc}$ or the other components neglects a gain of two. I chose to include it on $H_{uc}$; you could just as validly split it between $H_{max}$ and $H_{min}$ as a $\sqrt{2}$ factor.  I suppose I tend to neglect poles at zero and $\infty$.  That will mean your $H_{max}$ will not be causal.

Comment: How did you know that the scalar factor has to be $2$? I still don't understand why did you choose a pole inside the unit circle for $H_{max}(z)$

Comment: Because your selection of the three components came out a factor of 2 out (amongst other problems).

Comment: Your definition of **maximum phase** is bogus. Where do you get it from?  [This page](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Maximum_Phase_Filters.html) gives a more usual definition. This definition says nothing about pole positions; just zeros.

Comment: This is the definition of maximum phase that I use: the system has to be stable and anti-causal, so the ROC must include the unit circle ($|z|=1$) and it must not include $z=\infty$ (because it's anti-causal). So poles and zeros have to be outside the unit circle, isn't it?

Comment: This is what I get from Oppenheim-Schafer: "a sequence that has maximum-phase is a stable sequence that its Z transform has all the poles and zeros OUTSIDE the unit circle."

Comment: @Euler : I really believe O&S do not say that. I have looked at my copy, and they only reference zero locations. Not poles. Please provide the page / section / equation number where your "quote" came from.

Comment: Exercise 5.63, page 335 (Chapter 5 - Problems).

Comment: Interesting. I can see that on the exercise... but then on Figure 5.31 it says that sequence $h_b$ is maximum phase, but it is certainly not anti-causal. I'm looking at the second edition online; my paper copy is the first edition... which doesn't have Exercise 5.63 (though the online second edition does). I believe exercise 5.63 is in error.

Comment: @Euler : OK, so either the statement in Exercise 5.63 is wrong, or the relationship between $H_{max}$ and $H_{min}$ is wrong.

Comment: I think that the exercise 5.63 is wrong. Thanks Peter!

Comment: @Euler : You're welcome!  The checkmark pushed me over the 11k boundary. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Euler this is the similar problem I faced earlier and posted questions asking why all-pass filter is a maximum phase filter. My conclusion is that for spectral factorization purpose, the maximum phase filter must have all poles and zeros outside the unit circle. This is because for real H(z), H(z) == H^*(1/z^*). In this sense, the minimum phase filter of H(z) will become a maximum phase filter of H^*(1/z^*), and this maximum phase filter must be stable and anti-causal.